# Wait until operations in CustomKeywords finish to continue, Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, ui-automation, katalon-studio

I have a script using groovy in Katalon Studio. Basically the pseudocode is

```
 1. OpenBrowser 
 2. Login
 3. Get urls on page.
 4. Foreach urls
     a. Check(url)
 5. CloseBrowser
```

The CustomKeywords Check navigate to the url and do some checks in this page

I got usually around 200 url, and the check for the first 5 or 7 url works ok(it depends on speed of connection), but despite a certain moment, the check fails for the rest of the urls. I notice that when the script navigates to a url, the next url opens too fast, and for that reason, the check fails.

I tried to set a delay for Delay between actions in the Project Settings but take to much time in step 3 isn't the idea.

- How can I wait until step 4.a is finished to iterate to the next url?
- Is a sleep after step 4.a to assure that it finished necessary? Is it a good practice?

Fragment of step 4

```
for (def url: urls) {     
    CustomKeywords.'com.utilities.CommonUtilities.Check'(href)
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Is there something visible that changes on the page when the URL is checked? Is there an element you can see on the page you navigate to?

Comment: @MateMrše In fact I look for one element in my case in order to check that  when I navigate to the url wait for one element visible to continue the iteration, but in my case there isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the Wait commands in Katalon to wait for some element's presence or non-presence.

```
WebUI.waitForElementAttributeValue()
WebUI.waitForElementClickable()
WebUI.waitForElementHasAttribute()
WebUI.WaitForElementNotClickable()
WebUI.WaitForElementNotHasAttribute()
WebUI.WaitForElementNotPresent()
WebUI.WaitForElementNotVisible()
WebUI.WaitForElementPresent()
WebUI.WaitForElementVisible()
```

After that, you could still add a `WebUI.delay()` if needed.

Comment: Well In fact I solve my issue using WebUI.delay(5), but I need to add that on CustomKeywords  Check, just before begin the checking in that method, because this page use some js that run after load page for this reason my tests failed. Now my test take long time  but it works. Before I used WebUI.waitForPageLoad(5) but it was not enough

Comment: If you use some form of waitForElement....() commands, tests should be more flexible, i.e. Katalon will poll the element instead of using a fixed delay.